# WPF Email Sending error on polish server

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, email, smtp

This is the code for email sending, but it doesn't give any results, there are no errors , also in debugger there are no alerts:

```
public void EmailSending()
{
    try
    {
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("poczta.silesianet.pl", 587);
        smtp.Timeout = 20000;
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        NetworkCredential Credentials = new NetworkCredential("userName", PB_AddPassword.Password, "https://poczta.silesianet.pl/");
        smtp.Credentials = Credentials; 
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage("from@mail","to@mail");
        message.Subject = "Topic:"
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;
        message.Body = "Body";
        IntPtr accountToken = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Token;
        smtp.SendAsync(message, accountToken);
   }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }
    }
```

And this is the code for the password, but something is also wrong because it doesn't remember it :

```
private void PB_AssPassword_TextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    string Pass= PB_AssPassword.Password;
    hasło = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Pass");

    if (Pass== null)
    {
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("Pass", "Value1");
    }
}
```

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: what happens in the `catch` block?

Comment: it doesnt catch anything , thats why i posted this problem

Comment: sorry , im wrong :

smtp.ServicePoint.Address threw an exceptionof type 'System.NotSupportedException'

Comment: As @MattWilko asked, please post your catch & finally blocks also.

Comment: ok, i placed it above

Comment: @KubaKarmański is there an inner exception?